# Sencha Trouch 2: hbox titlebar items getting trimmed

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 button inside a titlebar as below

```
xtype: 'titlebar',
            cls: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            itemId: 'lookupBar',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'end'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    flex: 1,
                    itemId: 'btnBack',
                    ui: 'back'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    flex: 1,
                    align: 'right',
                    itemId: 'btnEntitySearch',
                    ui: 'forward'
                }
            ]
```

But if Text in this 2 button is large, then 2nd button getting trimmed ,
[image]

After looking in generated CSS, I can see that for first button we have a "
-webkit-box-flex: 1; width: 128px !important;
"

but it was not for 2nd button !!!

Any Idea what is wrong here ?

Additional images after applying Answers

[image: in case of small text, nothing comes up]

[image]

Comment: This is a normal behavior as you have given `align:'right'` in the button. If you remove that then you will see that none of the buttons text is getting wrapped up. What is your requirement?

Comment: I can see both the buttons are -webkit-box-flex: 1; And the scrolling is coming because you have not set this: scrollable : {
      direction     : 'vertical',
      directionLock : true
}

Comment: @SujataChanda , Yes I have given align:'right' as I want buttons to be on either end ; like one in Left and other in right side

Comment: @AnandGupta setting scrollable property on lookupBar item does not make much difference. Just that now size of First Button does not get shrink automatically.

Comment: Do you want to shrink the button automatically?

Comment: @SujataChanda  I want buttons to be on either end ; like one in Left side of view and other in right side of view.

This is working in case of Button Text is small, 
but when button text is large right side button gets cutoff.
Left side button is OK, as it shows as per flex (1) and additional text are trimmed (as ...) . And this is not happening in case of right side button

Comment: @AnandGupta , Yes as button on left side did (additional characters are replaced as '...') also it's have like max width

Comment: In the css which i have answered, you can replace width with max-width. Both will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you want to shrink the button if the text go large. You can simply apply ellipsis on button label as below, Apply this in your css file:

```
.x-toolbar .x-button-label {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 100px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another trick: Use this css only

```
.x-toolbar-inner .x-container {
    max-width: 45%;
}
```

This will work in all profile whether mobile or tablet

Comment: This Will set width to 100px;
But in case of tablet view or Landscape View in phone will set it so bit small .

Answer (score 0):

Without css you can do the wrapping also, Sencha gives the ellipsis property by itself on the titlebar buttons, so just need to mention a width/max-width like this:-

```
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            cls: 'toolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            itemId: 'lookupBar',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'btnBack',
                align: 'left',
                text: 'fdsfs gsdg gsadg dg',
                ui: 'back'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                width : '80%', // or width in px if you want or give a max-width
                align: 'right',
                text: 'fdsfs gsdg gsadg dg',
                itemId: 'btnEntitySearch',
                ui: 'forward'
            }
            ]
```

Comment: This suppose to work, but in couple of scenarios it's not working
 
1.In case of tablet view or Landscape View in phone there are empty space in right side.

2. In case of small text (like only 'Back') no text appearing in button.


I will add image in original Question, as I cannot post image here.

Comment: I have checked it in my browser but its working fine. Try removing the layout: hbox as I did.